# Returning keys from key-value pairs based on maximum value in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to apache spark and I need some advice. I have an RDD with [String, Int] type. RDD values are like that:

- ("A,x",3)
- ("A,y",4)
- ("A,z",1)
- ("B,y",2)
- ("C,w",5)
- ("C,y",2)
- ("E,x",1)
- ("E,z",3)

What I want to accomplish is to get an RDD like that (String,String):

- ("A","y") //among the key's that contains A, (A,y) has the max value
- ("B","y") //among the key's that contains B, (B,y) has the max value
- ("C","w") //among the key's that contains C, (C,w) has the max value
- ("E","z") //among the key's that contains E, (E,z) has the max value

I tried a loop concept (by using a counter) in flatMap but it doesn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reshape and `reduceByKey`:

```scala
val pattern = "^(.*?),(.*?)$".r

rdd
  // Split key into parts
  .flatMap{ case (pattern(x, y), z) => Some((x, (y, z))) }
  // Reduce by first part of the key
  .reduceByKey( (a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b )
  // Go back to the original shape
  .map { case (x, (y, z)) => (s"$x,$y", z) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @zero323 , you saved my day :) I haven't used regex until now, it seems pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy Key and then use the maxBy function to get your output

```
val data = Array(("A,x", 3),("A,y", 4),("A,z", 1),("B,y", 2),("C,w", 5),("C,y", 2),("E,x", 1),("E,z", 3))
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(data).map(i => { // Paralleling the sample data
val t = i._1.split(",")  // Splitting the String by , 
t(0) ->(t(1), i._2) // Transforming String,Int to String,(String,Int)
}).groupByKey().map(i => { // Performing a groupBy key 
(i._1, i._2.maxBy(_._2)._1) // returning the Max value by the Int being passed using the maxBy function 
})
rdd.foreach(println(_)) // Printing the output
```

Comment: Thank you @Vishnu667 , this one is more easier to implement, but I read that groupByKey is slow when data becomes too large. Can I use this code for a data about 20 gb?

Comment: It will definitely Run on 20GB of data but how long depends on the cluster your running it on. InTerms of performance I don't think there would be a great difference as Spark would optimize the `GroupByKey` and in my code the reducer is the `maxBy` function. Thus making it equivalent to @zero323 answer. Cause Internally Both of them use the same `combineByKey` function.

Comment: The best way to tell would be to run both my answer and the above answer on your set and let me know how it performs.

Comment: I'm running it on local with a small sample (~10 mb) so I cannot say anything now. In a few days we'll run it on the cluster, I'll tell you the result then. Thank you very much again for your brief answer.

Comment: By Set i meant your 20G file :)